# CRM 2013 | Plugin registration tool error

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to connect to pluginRegistration tool for CRM SDK 2013 and I get this error

```
Source  : mscorlib
Method  : HandleReturnMessage
Date    : 27-Jun-16
Time    : 7:56:13 AM
Error   : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
Stack Trace : Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery.IDiscoveryService.Execute(DiscoveryRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.DiscoveryServiceProxy.Execute(DiscoveryRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
   at >Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.CrmConnectionManager.ValidateServerConnection(CrmOrgByServer selectedOrg)
```

Could you help to get mor information and resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you double check to see if the plugin registration tool from the SDK's version matches CRM version?

Comment: Both are 2013 version

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the connection section?

Comment: Is it an online or onpremise? If onpremise, did you check the event viewer to see what's going on?

Comment: Did it worked before ? Can you try using another CRM user account ?

Comment: Its on premise environment and it worked before with CRM user account. It works if I restart IIS, but, stop after some seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it was due to one of our organizations sql database being offline.

In order to fix - you've got to first find out what the *actual* exception is. You can do this by enabling the detailed errors as it indicates in your exception message.

Here are some steps on how to do that.

https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/knowledge-base/enable-detailed-errors-on-the-organization-service/

Comment: My issue was ALSO that one of the OTHER Organizations on that server was offline... I guess that stops you from connecting to ANY that are on that same server.